# No logs from Grails 3.x application under Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, logback, logback-groovy

I have Grails 3.x application. It runs well on development machine and it's logging level in `grails-app/conf/logback.groovy` is set to `INFO`

Unfortunately, when I run on production server there are no any word from my application in logs.

I found several similar questions on this topic, but they are answering about log4j. This is probably about previous version of Grails. I have logback, not log4j.

So, what to do for Grails logging under Tomcat production environment?

Comment: I have seen reports about problems with logback on Grails 3. Issue was, that logback did not have permissions to default folder used. Try setting different path for production logs (somewhere outside of application server) and see if it works for you too.

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I cannot get the log using grails 3 under the tomcat.